# AZ CLI - List all resource group empty

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to list all resource group without any resources inside like disks, vm, ip address and others.
I have found this scirpt which is listing only resource group with resources but I want the opposite that is to list all resource group not contains ressources.

```
for i in `az group list -o tsv --query [].name`; do if [ "$(az resource list -g $i -o tsv)" ]; then echo "$i is not empty"; fi; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do with this simple command

```
az group list --query [].name --output json
```

EDIT :

i found a reference [here](https://lnx.azurewebsites.net/how-to-remove-all-empty-resource-groups-using-azure-cli/)

```
for i in `az group list -o tsv --query [].name`; do if [ "$(az resource list -g $i -o tsv)" ]; then echo "$i is not empty"; else az group delete -n $i -y --no-wait; fi; done
```

instead of delete you can print them

Comment: This will list all resource groups in the subscription and not the ones which are empty.

Comment: when I change "delete" to "list" it doesn't work as I want